# How to configure loopback-component-oauth2 to save token in cookies?

Tags: loopback

I'm trying to configure loopback-component-oauth2 to save access token in cookies, but can not find out how to do this. By default, access token is adding to '/auth/callback' route as part of hash. Example path:

```
http://localhost:3000/auth/callback#access_token=0bzaFOmVY6ICeArhzCGso27Cwc07d7k4&expires_in=1209600&token_type=Bearer
```

I saw in logger, that we can try to get access token after "Generating access token" stage, but I still do not understand, how to get it.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKUmA.png)